# Facing issue on service side validation

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to implement the server side validation using spring. but its not validating. Here is my code sample.

```
        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/api/v1/note")
        public class NoteController {

            @Autowired
            private final NoteService noteService;

            @PostMapping
            public ResponseEntity<String> create(@Valid @RequestBody final NoteDto noteDto){

                noteService.create(noteDto);
                return new ResponseEntity<>("sucess", HttpStatus.CREATED);
            }   
    }
```

POJO..

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
public class NoteDto {

    @NotEmpty(message = "Building No can't be empty!")
    private String buildingNo;

    private String buildingName;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Street can't be empty!")
}
```

What am missing here

Comment: What about POJO class?

Comment: Whats the error and post some stacktrace if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

@Valid annotation that triggers validations on the NoteDto (in this case @NotNull and @Future). These annotations could come from different JSR-303 providers (e.g, Hibernate, Spring..etc).

Example

> static class NoteDto {
>
> ```
>     @NotNull @Future
>     private Date date;
> }
> ```

And Remove final.